# Android zoomable/scrollable ImageView with overlays

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-imageview

I would like to display an image (including scroll and zoom functionality).
Additionally, I need to add some overlays to the image dynamically. The overlays are in a relationship to the content within the image.

- If the user scrolls, the overlays should move too
- If the user zooms,
  the overlays should not be zoomed but hold their relative position to
  the image

In other words: I'd like to implement a Map with some markers, but I provide my own map material.

My main question is: How could I do this?

**What I have tried so far**

- I tried to implement it within a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) as it provided the basic zooming and scaling functionality. However, I did not succeed in adding overlays without using Javascript and HTML (what I thought was not a very convenient way of solving the problem)
- There are projects (i.e. [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/example/touch/TouchImageView.java)) which are implementing the scroll/zoom functionality but they make it even harder to add own overlay functionality from my point of view.

**Questions**

Is there a simple solution or approach to my problem?

What is the right way of adding and moving views at runtime in Android?
(Usually, I would use a basic layout and play with the margin - would that be best practice?)

Could somebody point me to the right direction, please.

Min. API Level: 10

Comment: there is no easy way. TouchImageView is fine for starting point. All you need is to change onDraw method to draw your overlays before main image.

Comment: +1 I got the same problem but I implemented it without touch and zoom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time, I found the exact answer to my solution: [TileView](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView)

**Setting up the map view:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
  super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
  TileView tileView = new TileView( this );
  tileView.setSize( 2000, 3000 );  // the original size of the untiled image
  tileView.addDetailLevel( 1f, "tile-%d-%d.png");
  setContentView( tileView );
}
```

**Adding the marker:**

```
tileView.addMarker( someView, 250, 500, -0.5f, -1.0f );
```

Code from the documentation.

Comment: Can I custom TileView? I want to add TileView into a Fragment. This fragment contains both TextView, Button, RelativeLayout and TileView. How could I do this?

Comment: @OneOne I just overrode the TileView class and customised it as a I needed it. Most of the functionality I needed had been offered by the TileView however.

Comment: I'm in stuck this problem in a long time. Can u give me the example, please?

Comment: Were/are you using a single image or did you end up cutting it into tiles? I tried to go the "big, single image" route and gave the library a `Bitmap` but it doesn't display anything and it looks like you actually need the images as assets.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest extending the `View` class and overriding `onDraw` method.
Take a look at the [Canvas API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html).

You'll probably have an onDraw method that looks like :

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY); //position of your actual data
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor); // zoom factor
    map.draw(canvas); //you draw your map here
    canvas.restore(); //go back to saved state 
    //for each marker you have, do the same "save - translate - scale - draw" loop        
}
```

Since you don't need your markers to be zoomable, you'll probably wont need scale step but you need to calculate their position properly.

Depending on your # of objects etc, you may need to have a more optimized way of drawing your markers (e.g. re-drawing only changed rectangular areas). see [View.invalidate(Rect)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28android.graphics.Rect%29)

Answer (score 1):

I Think this one can help you

Refer this project [Link](https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo)

it Has a Automatic Scrolling of Image and Zoom a Image When you click On it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried subclassing View and handling yourself user gestures? It is my first choice for complex behaviours as such. It should look something like this:

- In your class extending View you should instantiate the required image and overlays at creation time as Bitmap objects
- OnScroll event you will calculate how the image and overlays chould be after such scroll, refresh the Bitmaps and invalidate the current view
- Using a GestureDetector, you can handle pinch events and treat zoom in/zoom out events just as scroll events
- Remember to always call invalidate after changing your Bitmaps
- Draw the bitmaps during the onDraw method

Plenty of material about this individual tasks on StackOverflow, let me know if you need adittional help in any of these.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this example project https://github.com/jzafrilla/AndroidImageHostpot