# Android ImageView Zoom with text overlay

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, pinchzoom

I want to overlay `textview` on `imageview` on android which I have done programatically. I also want that image should be able to zoom in and zoom out which also I am able to done. But I am stuck in a problem of placing text on image in such a way that while I zoom image then text should not zoom and it should stay on the same position on the image not on the screen.

Comment: Do you have tried to add the TextView as View to the ImageView and overriding the gesture-listeners?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004424/android-zoomable-scrollable-imageview-with-overlays?rq=1

Comment: @TobiasK. what do you mean by adding "add the TextView as View to the ImageView"  ? Can ImageView have child elements ?

Comment: I wanted to place an textview over an imageview. Afterwards i wanted to resize the text on pinch to zoom gestures, but now i do not remember how i solved this whether is used different elements.

Answer (score 6):

OK, I created an XML layout that fits your needs. All you have to do is zoom in or out of the image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="287dp"
        android:layout_height="287dp"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Hello Constant Text Overlay"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>
        <!-- Don't want it centered? Then change the layout gravity to fit your needs -->

</FrameLayout>
```

With this, you can easily modify the width and height of the ImageView and the TextView will remain in the center without getting larger or smaller.

I noticed that you took a programmatic solution, and you can easily look at how it is done via XML and convert that to code.

What is important here is that you have a container around your ImageView that wraps the content. Inside of that you have the ImageView of specified width/height, and a TextView that is centered horizontally and vertically in the container.

You can do whatever you want to do with the Image now, the text will remain untouched; just it will remain in the center

Comment: This is a way to go if he wants centered text, but if he wants text in some other position then zed's comment is excellent approach.

Comment: I added a comment to explain how to change if from being centered. There are a plethora of positions that my solution works for correctly. This is also one of the simplest solutions

Comment: Also, if the user does not want it in one of the locations determined by `layout_gravity`, then they can add additional attributes like margins and such