# Zoom and pan ImageView with overlay (SimpleOnScaleGestureListener/SimpleOnGestureListener)

Tags: java, android, imageview, gesturelistener

My app (Java 8/min API 24/target API 27) displays an image (loaded from app storage at runtime) using an `ImageView` that I want to zoom into and also pan while it's zoomed in.

I'm aware there are already questions about it but most of them were asked in 2012 or 2013 and the accepted answers usually say: "Use a library" (e.g. [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)), which I probably can't because: I also want to draw on the image, e.g. a filled circle with a text next to it that then moves with the image but isn't zoomed. Think of it as a map (single image, around 2000x2000) with map markers that always stay in the same spot on the map (= same x/y coordinate), even when it's panned.

I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14004424/2016165) question from 2012 but the suggested library ([TileView](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView)) unfortunately requires the image to be divided into tiles, which are stored as assets.

That's why I started implementing zooming myself by using a `ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` ([source](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/android-detecting-a-pinch-gesture-64a0a0ed4b41)):

```
ScaleGestureDetector sgd = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new MyPinchListener());
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        sgd.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
});
```

This calls the listener's e.g. `onScaleEnd` automatically and I then draw the according part of the image bitmap onto a `Canvas` and add that to the `ImageView` :

```
Bitmap bitmapCanvas = Bitmap.createBitmap(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels,getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapFile,srcRect,dstRect,paint);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapCanvas);
```

There's full code for zoom and pan detection [here](https://gist.github.com/alphamu/eca221f76f1505c9fede) but, while it works, it doesn't use `SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` or `SimpleOnGestureListener` (which has `onScroll`) but instead tries to find the type of gesture itself.

**Question:** How do I combine these two listeners in `onTouch`, so I can take advantage of their `on...` methods? Is there a less complicated way than what the full code I linked above does?

If there's a library (free to use and still supported!) that does scrolling/panning with a single, big image and also allows adding some type of overlay (I need to know what pixel area is currently being display), please feel free to suggest it as an alternative.